# Why doesn't anything happen in using QgsRasterCalculator on a list?

Tags: pyqgis, raster-calculator, list

I have a list of raster layers that I want to do a calculation on each layer with **QgsRasterCalculator**. My code is:

```
lstLyr = self.readRasters()

    for layer in lstLyr:
        registry = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance()
        lyr = registry.mapLayersByName(layer)
        namlyr = lyr[0].name()

        output = "/LorDataPlugin/Data/Temps/Normlized_%s.tif" % str(namlyr)

        fileName = layer
        fileInfo = QFileInfo(fileName)
        baseName = fileInfo.baseName()
        lyr2 = QgsRasterLayer(fileName, baseName)

        entries = []

        ras1 = QgsRasterCalculatorEntry()
        ras1.ref = namlyr + '@1'
        ras1.raster = lyr2
        ras1.bandNumber = 1
        entries.append(ras1)

        formula = ras1.ref + '/' + str(self.sumValue(lyr2))

        calc = QgsRasterCalculator(formula, output, 'GTiff', lyr2.extent(), lyr2.width(), lyr2.height(), entries)

        calc.processCalculation()
```

But when run it without any error message, nothing happens. what is error in this code?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is there's probably an issue with your `formula`. I would suggest to enclose the name of the layer in double quotation marks, this is useful especially when you have layer names which include more than one word separated by a 'space' (as the raster calculator will likely interpret this as being two different objects).

Try replacing your formula:

```
formula = ras1.ref + '/' + str(self.sumValue(lyr2))
```

with

```
formula = "\"" + ras1.ref + "\"" + ' / ' + str(self.sumValue(lyr2))
```

Comment: Hi @Joseph, I used your suggestion but not work. Sorry I think the problem relate to `baseName = fileInfo.baseName()` and `lyr2 = QgsRasterLayer(fileName, baseName)` because when I test in`QMessageBox.Warning` after this lines it shows the layer name instead of file path. I remember that my layers come from combobox Qt.

Comment: @nickan - Can you explain what your code is _supposed_ to do please? I'm a little confused as it seems you're taking the first raster in the list and dividing this by all following rasters. Is that the case?

Comment: Sorry for my delay response. I build a QGIS plugin that it get some raster file by Combo Box. Then I want to divide each raster file to sum value of all value raster of each raster layer.